# GTX 860M stuck to 33 Mhz after suspend on linux

Tags: linux, drivers, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, suspend

With the official nvidia driver, whenever I enter suspend mode and return, the GPU clock is set to 33 Mhz and stays there no matter what I do.

- Kernel: 3.19.2-1-ARCH
- Driver: 346.47
- Hardware: MSI GE60 2PE Apache Pro, GTX 860M
- OS: Arch Linux x64

It happens with both [disabled Intel graphics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus#Using_nvidia) and [Bumblebee](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee).

After rebooting it works properly again, until the next suspend.

As you an see here, the performance level is 2 with a minimum of 135 Mhz, but the actual clock speed is still at 33:
[image: screenshot of nvidia-settings/PowerMizer]

The only entry popping up in X logs on suspend is this this one:

```
[  2953.091] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
```

In the [official driver information](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/82252/en-us) it says 9xx cards have problems with resuming from suspend, might that affect 8xx cards aswell?

Comment: This is simple enough to confirm.  You should roll the driver back to the previous release and confirm the problem goes away.

Comment: All previous packages I have access to depend on an older kernel version, instead of trying to downgrade the kernel too I'll see if editing the package file works.

Comment: So you updated the `Nvidia` drivers and the kernel?

Comment: Last week ago, but I don't know if it worked before then.

Comment: I haven't managed to downgrade, and the problem persists in `nvidia-beta` (which is 349.12)

Comment: I would start with the assumption that the warning about this problem existing applies to products outside of just 9xx cards.  Which means you Nvidia forums might get the right people involved.